# css nav ul not working

Tags: css, html

I made a new website and my problem is that the menu is ok in FF and other browsers, but not in IE.

The problem is, it wont list the list elements, no hover , no color, and not inline.

here is the code

```
nav {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

nav ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 297px;

}

nav li  {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 65px;
    background: url(images/line.png) no-repeat right 10px;
    height: 72px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

} 

nav li a {
    color: #656464;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

nav li:hover {
    background: url(images/hover.png) repeat-x 0 35px;
    color: #242424;
}
```

could please someone could give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nav` is an HTML5 element; old IEs will not recognize it and thus won't apply your styles.

To make IE recognize HTML5 markup, place the [HTML5 shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) on your page, then declare a rule for `nav` and any other HTML5 elements you use, giving them a `display: block` style, just above the CSS that you have now.

Comment: header, nav, article, footer, address is added to the top of the css as block, shiv is added, but still not working :S

Comment: ok i feel really dumb.

the problem was the shiv, i didnt linked it liked it like

<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

it was linked as 

<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.s"></script>

really sorry and thank you for the replyes

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

`<nav>` is fine to use on a page, but you will run into problems with it when you try and style it as many browsers simply skip the tag if they don't understand it.

Wrap the `<nav>` tag in a wrapper div and style that instead, and strip away any styling from the semantic tags so they are naked.

Comment: this should be selected as correct as it does not add anything to the mix...